# dynamic drop down list in php

Tags: php, html

i am using a dynmamic drop down list in php which is working perfectly fine but the html code after  tag is not being executed

my view page is inside a folder ekart in views folder the view page is
Product.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
        <title>
        ADD PRODUCT               
        </title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>ADD PRODUCT</h1>
        <form id="admin" action="/do/ekart/adminlogin/login/" method="POST">
        Category Name :<br/>
        <select name="category" id="category">
        <option value="select">Select...</option> 
        <?php
           foreach($result as $row)
             {
               echo "<option value='".$row['cat_name']."> ".$row['cat_name'</option>";
             }
        ?>
        </select><br/>
        Product Name:<br/>
        <input type="text" name="product" id="product"/><div id="product_display"></div><br/>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
        </body>
</html>


the $result is an array which is passed by the controller
$data=array('result'=>$result);
$this->load->view('ekart/Product.php',$data);
```

now the drop down list is showing the correct output but the html code written below it is not executed..
that is no Product name: tag,input field and submit button is shown in the browser..

Comment: line 
echo "<option value='".$row['cat_name']."> ".$row['cat_name'</option>";

is 
echo "<option value='".$row['cat_name']."> ".$row['cat_name']."</option>";

the code is still not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all wrong:

```
echo "<option value='".$row['cat_name']."> ".$row['cat_name'</option>";
```

It should be:

```
echo "<option value='".$row['cat_name']."'> ".$row['cat_name']."</option>";
```

Comment: i have missed a ' but still it not showing any error when i am inspecting element with firebug.

Comment: Because it's not considered an error. Closing tag `</option>` can be omitted if it's followed by another `<option>` ([w3 reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html))