# How to add options to PHP/HTML select/option

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a select box populated (from mysql db) with street names and is working fine.  What would be the correct procedure to add a new street that does not currently exist?

Comment: Can you put the aproach you have taken up to now? Did you use AJAX?

Comment: code? code!... code :(.... where is the code? ... :(

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603755/dynamic-drop-down-list-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it using datalist